# Distinguishing between single and multiple characters while using get()?

Tags: c++

The `get()` function is used to read a single character and to read multiple characters into an array. How does the system know if it is to read a single character or multiple characters?

Comment: Think about how you call the function in the two cases.

Comment: To clarify, [we're discussing this `get` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get), yes?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the parameters you specify, it will direct the calls to the matching prototype of the function.

For example if you call `get(character reference)` it will consider that one *character* has to be read from the stream.

If you pass a *string* (pointer) as argument and specify the length, it will consider reading characters in stream uptil that length in `get(string, stream length)`.

If you specify a delimiter (add a `'delimiter character'` to the parameters above) it will read uptil that character is matched against.

If you specify a *stream-buffer* using `get(streambuf)` it will read all the *available* characters. (can add a delimiter here as well)

Evident from the above, only the first prototype `get(character reference)` or `get(char& c)` reads a single character, rest read multiple characters (eg: passing a string/stream-buffer with length), and this is known by the parameters you provide or the function prototype you follow during your call to `get()`. [Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)

Comment: @bee3 Consider accepting an answer if it helps! Also if you have any questions, feel free to ask.